# Log file remains empty after tests are run with log writes

Tags: python, pytest, python-logging

I hit this problem with log file staying empty despite two different tests using log writes. The directory and the log file are created after test runs, if I try to delete them. I do see the live logging in on the terminal screen.

Here's what I have:

- log configurations in .ini file that is placed at the root directory of the project:

  ```ini
  log_cli = 1
  log_cli_level = WARN
  log_cli_format = %(message)s

  log_file = log/pytesting.log
  log_file_level = DEBUG
  log_file_format = %(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] [%(name)s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%lineno)s)
  log_file_date_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M%S
  ```
- Testing function in one file:

  ```
  import logging
  LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


  def test_myLoggings():
      LOGGER.warning("Warning Log")
      LOGGER.error("Error Log")
      LOGGER.critical("Critical Log")
      assert True
  ```
- Test function in another file:

  ```
  def test_updatingPet():
      payload = {"id": int(petID), "name": "Cutie", "status": "pending"}
      data, resp_status, timeTaken = putData(baseURI, payload)
      LOGGER.info("API call done")
      assert data["id"] == int(petID)
      print(data)
  ```

Trying to debug this:

1. I tried running these test functions via the IDE terminal and windows CMD. The commands I used were either `pytest -v -k <name of function` or `pytest <path to test file>`.
2. This happens in Visual Studio Code and in PyCharm Community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `log_file_format` is invalid. Commenting out that line populates the file as expected --

```
WARNING  tests.test_foo:test_foo.py:6 Warning Log
ERROR    tests.test_foo:test_foo.py:7 Error Log
CRITICAL tests.test_foo:test_foo.py:8 Critical Log
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I has a missing opening parenthesis:
`log_file_format = %(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] [%(name)s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%lineno)s)`
Instead of
`log_file_format = %(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] [%(name)s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)`
Thanks!